# MongoDB and BIRT Reporting?

Tags: mongodb, reporting, birt

Has anyone used BIRT to generate reports from MongoDB, can you describe how, any issues, etc. ?

It looks like it might be possible to interface using JDBC and this experimental driver:
https://github.com/erh/mongo-jdbc

However, I am not exactly sure how to install this driver in eclipse to test it.

Answer (score 4):

I've successfully integrated BIRT with MongoDB - it works perfectly well.
The idea is this - define a scripted data source in BIRT, then define a data set that using that data source. The data set has an "open" event in which you place the call to Mongo Java Driver and execute your query against MongoDB (and obtain a DB Cursor). Then in the "fetch" event you basically get the next value of the Cursor, filling data from the Cursor into the data set.

This is possible because BIRT scripts utilize RHINO Javascript engine which has Java integration. Place the MongoDB java driver in the classpath and start coding :)

Comment: So the data set is java code-   Can you paste an example of what you wrote for the open , fetch?

Answer (score 3):

Try this http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/mongodb-oda-birt-plugin/

Let me know if you face issues. The user guide available in the Downloads section should be able to help you with the usage of the ODA.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting ODA. i have been trying to use Command Expression Builder and I'm getting `org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.OdaException: Error in parsing the JSON expression`. I couldn't find a manual how write expressions correctly. I would greatly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3):

Birt has builtin support now for MongoDB :)
http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/project/notable4.3.php#jump_5

Answer (score 1):

The JDBC has only one checkin for more as a year. I think the JDBC driver project is dead. JDBC and NoSQL are not compatible.

I think you need to write your own layer that create relational data from your NoSQL.