# How to install a JDBC driver in BIRT Reporting for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jdbc, mongodb, birt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MongoDB and BIRT Reporting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322506/mongodb-and-birt-reporting)

I am trying to install a JDBC driver in to eclipse - specifically the BIRT tool in eclipse.  I tried going to the add data source and clicking manage drivers, then adding in the JAR file, but that does not seem to give me anything new to select when setting up a data source.

I am trying to add in the [mongodb jdbc driver](https://github.com/erh/mongo-jdbc).

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB doesn't look like it would work with BIRT in this way now. I have tried to tweak mongo driver a bit to appear in BIRT Driver Classes and to work, but not succesfully at all.

Generally, I think Scripted Data Source will be good choice here. BIRT supports rather usual SQL-databases as JDBC Data Sources. Mongo has quite different approach, so Scripted Data Source may be only way to do the job.

Example: http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseBIRT/article.html#data.